# ajax post multiple parameters does not pass properly to asp.net mvc action

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I am not able to pass 2 parameters to the action method as json. I have the following ASP.net MVC3 action.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Create( PatientContactEpisodes patientcontactepisode, IList<PatientContactEpisodeProcedures> patientcontactepisodeprocedures)
```

And my ajax post looks like this.

```
     $("#SaveButton")
        .button()
        .click(function () {
            var episode = getpatientcontactepisode();
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            traditional: true,
            url: "/User/PatientContactEpisodes/Create",
            contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8',
            data: {patientcontactepisode: JSON.stringify(episode), patientcontactepisodeprocedures: JSON.stringify(createArray)},
            //data: JSON.stringify(episode),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (results) {                                                           
                alert("success");
            }
        });
     });
```

**ISSUE**

The issue is that the value does not seem to be passed when I send both parameters to the action. Both are null/empty. Whereas, when i send a single parameter

```
    //data: JSON.stringify(episode), or //data: JSON.stringify(createarray),
```

The above works fine.

Comment: Are you sure that the right controller is being called? Your ajax type is `Post` but I do not see `[HttpPost]` decorated on your action.

Comment: @TravisJ Yes, Sorry for not adding the attribute there. Yes, the controller action is being called. When I debug, I can see it getting called. When I pass the "data: JSON.stringify(episode)", the first parameter gets passed properly and the second parameter is empty and when I pass "data:JSON.stringify(createarray)" the second parameter gets passed properly. But, I just cant get both to pass properly at the same time. I think, syntax wise the ajax post looks fine? but when I send as the one I mentioned in code, (specifying the parameters) both are null.

Comment: Try and add quotations marks to "patientcontactepisode" and "patientcontactepisodeprocedures"

Comment: @Mihai Tried it already. data: {"patientcontactepisode": JSON.stringify(episode), "patientcontactepisodeprocedures": JSON.stringify(createArray)}.

Comment: Did a workaround. Passed the second paramter as a property of the first one and passed as just data:JSON.stringify(episode) instead of 2 parameters. Able to pass the second parameter successfully to the action method.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

**data: {JSON.stringify({patientcontactepisode: episode, patientcontactepisodeprocedures:createArray})},**

This should do the stuff for you.